# Is the book 'Gatherings of Conversations', containing transcriptions of speeches by Rebbe M.M. Shneerson, available anywhere?

Tags: jewish-books, chabad

From 'Jewish Fundamentalism in Israel' by I. Shahak and N. Mezvinsky we read ...

"The ideas of Rabbi Schneerson that appear below are taken from a book of his recorded
messages to followers in Israel, titled Gatherings of Conversations and
published in the Holy Land in 1965."

Is this book available to see, download, or purchase, anywhere?  Are the recordings available?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a minute to look over our [tour] since MY might work differently from other sites you’re used to. Thank you for bringing your question here, and hope you find the answers you seek!

Comment: Maybe they are refering to Likkutei Sichos

Comment: It's important to note that Shahak, at least, is a known and self-admitted liar, and deliberately slants his quotations to make Jews sound as bad as possible. So anything he "quotes" from Rabbi Schneerson, or from anywhere else, has to be checked against the original very carefully.

Comment: If there are any quotes from _Gatherings of Conversations_ in _Jewish Fundamentalism in Israel_, maybe add them to the question. People who don't have access to _Jewish Fundamentalism in Israel_ may be able to recognize the quotes, and provide cites to their sources.

Comment: 'Gatherings of Conversations' is the English translation of the book title 'Likkutei Sichot' which is an actual printed collection of talks from the Rebbe which the Rebbe personally reviewed. The printing arm of Kehot based in Kfar Chabad does much of the actual printing and bindery work. To my knowledge, only a portion of that book has been translated into English by Kehot. But it has been a while since I looked at the English translations.  It is possible that the entire collection has been translated by now. The original is available from Kehot currently.

Comment: Here is the link to Kehot for the set titled Likkutei Sichot: https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HRE-LS.S

Answer (score 2):

Unless the talks were delivered on Shabbos or Holidays when audio recording is forbidden, all of the Rebbe's conversations from 1950 to 1992 can be found here: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/sichoskodesh_cdo/jewish/Sichos-Kodesh.htm

Comment: Even the ones on Shabbos and holidays were transcribed from memory afterwards.